# How to pass selected item id from dropdown list to controller's action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**General problem overview:** I have a create\edit view for a compound item, where I select lots of options for components from drop down lists. I want to be able to add or edit a specific component, selected in a dropdown list.

**Here is a short, but complete example**:

Suppose I have a `Car` model

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BodyStyle BodyStyle { get; set; }
    public int BodyStyleId { get; set; }
}
```

`BodyStyle` is a component of a `Car` aggregate, defined as:

```
public class BodyStyle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a controller action to create a car,

```
public ActionResult CreateCar()
{
    //BodyStyles is a mock property with all hardcoded BodyStyles, just for demo
    ViewBag.Styles = new SelectList(BodyStyles, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

Here is the part of the `CreateCar` view, which defines `BodyStyle` dropdown list.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BodyStyle, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BodyStyleId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Styles)
        @Html.ActionLink("Create", "CreateBodyStyle")

        @*here is the problem, can't find a way to pass selected BodyStyle Id to EditBodyStyle action*@
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBodyStyle") 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the naive implementation of `EditBodyStyle`

```
public ActionResult EditBodyStyle(int bodyStyleId)
{
    return View(BodyStyles.First(b => b.Id == bodyStyleId));
}
```

**Is there a way to say to ASP.NET MVC to pass the selected BodyStyle Id from `DropDownListFor` to `EditBodyStyle` action?**

I've achieved this with javascript, subscribing to `onchange` and storing the selected value, then using it in the link. But the code becomes a **mess**, since I have near 10 of such components on several views. The functionality is quite simple, so I wonder if I'm missing some ASP.NET MVC feature, that will help me achieve this only using Razor view engine.

Here is the resulting view, just to get the whole picture:

[image]

Where each option of `select` tag is of format:

```
<option value="1">Coupe - 2 door</option>
<option value="2">Coupe - 3 door</option>
```

**Current implementation** (there is no id's in the view example above, but assume dropdown list and link has ids, as noted in the js):

```
$(function () {
    $("#editBodyStyleLink").click(function () {
        var id = $("#bodyStylesDropDown").val();
        window.location.href = "/Home/EditBodyStyle/?id=" + id;
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/593787/HowplustoplusPassplusDropdownplusselectplusvaluepl

Comment: @jbontinck I've noted about the first one, I'm using it right now and it's, well, ok. I'm not against writing JS, but wonder if this can be done without it. Solution 2 has `onchange = "submit();"` which means one action will handle all changes in dropdown lists, it's not desirable, since I want to dispatch edit actions on view level, not controller level.

Comment: Without javascript? Why don't you post form to `EditBodyStyle`? Is it must to use ActionLink here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to post your bodyStyleId as a parameter (please note I have used Cars for your controller name, you will need to change that to the actual controller name):

```
   <div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BodyStyle, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BodyStyleId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Styles)
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "CreateBodyStyle")

    @*here is the problem, can't find a way to pass selected BodyStyle Id to EditBodyStyle action*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBodyStyle", null, new { bodyStyleId = model.BodyStyleId) 
</div>
```

Then you need to select it when populating your select list items and send it back to the view:

```
public ActionResult EditBodyStyle(int bodyStyleId)
{
    var styles = BodyStyles.Select(m => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = m.Name,
                    Selected = bodyStyleId.Equals(m.Id.ToString())

                });
    ViewBag.Styles = styles;
    return View(model);
}
```

The important part which caught me out when doing this is the following line which selects the list:

```
 Selected = bodyStyleId.Equals(m.Id.ToString())
```

And finally use this for you dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BodyStyleId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Styles, "Please select")
```

Comment: Sorry, not quite getting you. How would `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBodyStyle")` know what id to pass to action?

Comment: The user selects the dropdown, we can't set it from server side. This answer is invalid.

Comment: Submitting with form is the only way that I know. (without javascript)

Comment: This would result in 10 form on a page? I'm having quite a few of components

Comment: Sorry I re-arranged my answer to make a bit more sense.

Comment: I've added **current implementation** section at the end of the question. How do you think, is that easier, than having multiple forms on a view with passing Car model into a `EditBodyStyle` action?

Comment: Hi, Yes that would work if you prefer it. I also updated it to include the get method which passes parameter across like this: @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBodyStyle", null, new { bodyStyleId = model.BodyStyleId) , that passes it in the url without using the post. Updated answer to reflect this. let me know how u get on. :)

Comment: `Model.BodyStyleId` will result in `NullReferenceException`, there is no model yet in `CreateCar` action

Comment: Yes sorry I see that now. Yes, I think your solution would be best. Let me know if this is no good and i'll remove answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write A javascript framework which could be reused every where.
You have to use Javascript.

You may approach like this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BodyStyleId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Styles,new{@class="traceable",targetid="changeLink",url="/yourcontroller/EditBodyStyle/"})

<a id="changeLink" href="#">Edit</a>
```

And Write a script

```
$(function(){
$('.traceable').change(function(){
var id=$(this).val();
var target=$(this).attr('tragetid'); 
var url=$(this).attr('url');
$('#'+target).attr('href',url+id);
});
});
```